Projective representations of $U(1)$
Let $G$ be a Lie group and $T:G\to GL(H)/\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ be a projective unitary representation in a Hilbert space $H$: i.e. for all $f,g\in G$, $$T(f)T(g)=e^{iC(f,g)}T(fg),\tag{*}$$ where $C$ is some real function on $G\times G$ and $T(f)$ is an unitary operator for all $f$. In the literature, the simplest example of projective representations arises with the group $U(1)=\{ e^{i\theta}:\theta\in [0,2\pi)\}$. I have two related question here:
(1) Why any exact irreducible, unitary representation of $U(1)$ takes the form $$T_s:U(1)\to \mathbb{C}^{\times}:\quad e^{i\theta}\mapsto e^{is\theta}$$ where $s\in \mathbb{Z}$?
(2) For which valeus of $s$, $T_s$ is projective?
My try: For (1), we have a theorem that says every exact irreducible unitary of a compact abelian Lie group $A$ is one-dimensional and takes the form $$T_p:A\to \mathbb{C}^{\times}:\quad \alpha \mapsto e^{ip(\alpha)}$$ where $p\in A^*$. Here $U(1)$ is a compact abelian Lie group. The remaining thing to me is that what is $U(1)^*$? Is $\mathbb{Z}$?
For (2), I tried to prove for any non-ineteger $s\in \mathbb{R}$, $T_s$ is projective but it is exact as  $$T(e^{i\theta_1})T(e^{i\theta_2})=e^{is\theta_1}e^{is\theta_2}=e^{si(\theta_1+\theta_2)}=T(e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)})!$$ I couldn't show that the relation $(*)$ is satisfied.

What is $\mathbb{C}^\times$? I've never seen that notation before.

@Sebastian Riese: Group of units/invertible elements.

The relation (*) is trivially satisfied by taking $C=0$. The unitary dual of $U(1)$ is indeed $\mathbb Z$ but this is just a restatement of the original problem. To actually prove (1) you can start by looking at the homomorphisms of Lie algebras.

@MoisheKohan Thank you very much for the comment. Could you please tell me why the dual of $U(1)$ is $\mathbb{Z}$? I don't know the Lie algebras. Could you please guide me?

Dual of $U(1)$ is ${ f:U(1)\to \mathbb{R}}$ where $f$ is a linear transformation. What is unitary dual?

For abelian groups, such as $U(1)$, this is the same as the Pontryagin dual, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality.
